# Переход из TableViewCell в tableviewCell (Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse.com

Столкнулся с проблемой при переходе с одного `TableviewCell` и представлении сцены `TableViewCell`.
Сначала сделал проект: представление темы `ViewController`. У меня массив  разделен на две части. При открытии сцены `TableViewCell` выдает одинаковую информацию любого объекта.
Вот код, который использую:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class PrognozSegmentViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {




        var soccerString = [Soccer]()
        var basketString = [Basketball]()
        var tennisString = [Tennis]()



    @objc var refresh : UIRefreshControl!




    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBAction func btnSegment(_ sender: Any) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





        refresh = UIRefreshControl()
        refresh.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Обновление")

        refresh.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
        refresh.addTarget(self, action:#selector(obnova), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        tableView.addSubview(refresh)
        setupSeg()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"TableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "sportCell")


        loadObjects1()
        loadObjects2()
        loadObjects3()


    }




    func setupSeg() {

        let attributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.yellow,
                           NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)];
        let attributesSelected = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
                                   NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)];

        segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: UIControlState.normal)
        segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesSelected, for: UIControlState.selected)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            return soccerString.count
        }
        else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            return basketString.count


        }
        else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            return tennisString.count

        }
        return 0
    }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


                if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0  {


                 let insertRow = (soccerString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                 let soccer = soccerString[insertRow]

                sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS

                sportCell.dataSave.text = soccer.dataMatchS
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: soccer.createdAt!)




                    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
                    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

                    sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday! ) // y



                soccerString[insertRow].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
                    }
                }
                else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                let newIndex = (basketString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                let basket = basketString[newIndex]
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: basket.createdAt!)




                    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
                    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

                    sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday! )
                basketString[newIndex].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                    sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

                }  else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

                 let newInt = (tennisString.count - 1) - indexPath.row
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[newInt].matchT

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: tennisString[newInt].createdAt!)




                    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
                    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
                    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

                    sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday! )

                tennisString[newInt].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                        sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }

         }



            sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none


            return sportCell
 }









    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }



    @objc func loadObjects1() {

        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>


        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.soccerString = objects!



                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })



            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
            }


        func loadObjects2() {
        let query = Basketball.query() as! PFQuery<Basketball>

        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {


                self.basketString = objects!
                self.tableView.reloadData()


            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

        }
    }

    func loadObjects3() {
        let query = Tennis.query() as! PFQuery<Tennis>


        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {


                self.tennisString = objects!



                self.tableView.reloadData()


            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

        }
    }



    @objc func obnova() {


            loadObjects1()
            loadObjects2()
            loadObjects3()
            tableView.reloadData()
            refresh.endRefreshing()


    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {


        case 0 :
                if segue.identifier == "showSoccer" {

             let destationViewController = segue.destination as! DetailSoccerTableViewController

                 if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                 let row = Int((soccerString.count-1)-indexPath.row)


                        destationViewController.detailSoccer = soccerString[row]


                    }
            }

          case 1 :
                if segue.identifier == "showBasket" {
                    let dvc = segue.destination as! DetailBasketViewController
                    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                        let row = Int((basketString.count-1)-indexPath.row)
                        dvc.baskets = basketString[row]

                    }

            }

             case 2 :
                if segue.identifier == "showTennis" {
                let destationVC: DetailTennisViewController = segue.destination as! DetailTennisViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    let row = Int((tennisString.count-1)-indexPath.row)
                    destationVC.tenises = tennisString[row]



                   }
                }
                default :
                break



            }
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSoccer", sender: self)

        } else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBasket", sender: self)

        } else if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTennis", sender: self)
        }
    }



}


   import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageSoccer: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    private let kTableHeaderHeigh:CGFloat = 300
    var headerView:UIView!



    var detailSoccer: Soccer!

    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 288
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")


        tableView.reloadData()
        loadMatchSoccer()
           //Header
         headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        tableView.addSubview(headerView)
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: kTableHeaderHeigh, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeigh)
        updateHeaderView()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func updateHeaderView() {
        var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeigh, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeigh)
        if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeigh {
            headerRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
            headerRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
        }
        headerView.frame = headerRect
    }



    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateHeaderView()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return selectedSoccer.count
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell", for: indexPath) as! SoccerTableViewCell

        let selectedSoccerRow = selectedSoccer[indexPath.row]


        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
        soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Описание:"
        soccerCell.textSoccer.text = selectedSoccerRow.textSoccer


        case 1:
        soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
        soccerCell.textSoccer.text = selectedSoccerRow.detailPrognozS
        default:
            break
        }


        return soccerCell

    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }







    func loadMatchSoccer() {

        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
        query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {

                self.selectedSoccer = objects!

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })



            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

    }
    }

}

Используя ViewController , а не TableviewCell. И передача данные в сцену происходила отлично, и корректное отображение данных.
 я замыкающий код использовал этот :  
if let object = baskets {

    self.textBasket.text = object["detailTextB"] as? String
    self.prognozBasket.text = object["detailPrB"] as? String
    self.titleBasket.text = object["detailTitleB"] as? String
    let imageFile = object["detailImageB"] as? PFFile
    imageFile?.getDataInBackground() { (data:Data?, error:Error?)->Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let imageData = data {
                self.imageBasket.image = UIImage(data: imageData)




            }

        }

    }
}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJABR.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед переходом на `DetailSoccerTableViewController` Вы его настраиваете с помощью переменной `detailSoccer`, которая, скорее всего, хранит информацию о том, какой конкретно футбольный матч выбрал пользователь (Ваше приложение я не видел, поэтому лишь излагаю свои предположения). Однако в `DetailSoccerTableViewController` Вы используете данную переменную лишь для настройки заголовка, хотя у Вас в функции `loadMatchSoccer` происходит загрузка данных, которые Вы фильтруете почему-то вот так:

```
query.whereKey("soccer", equalTo: selectedSoccer)
```

При этом `selectedSoccer` - это массив, в котором хранится информация, полученная с сервера. Настоятельно рекомендую Вам проверить данный фильтр, потому что он явно бесполезен и из-за него Вы всегда будете видеть одни и те же данные в `DetailSoccerTableViewController`. Наверное у Вас получится что-то вроде:

```
query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
```

Это при условии, что `detailTitleS` - ключ, по которому Вы определяете уникальность записи в таблице матчей. Если не получится разобраться, добавьте тогда больше информации о классе `Soccer` и о схеме, используемой Вами на сервере.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72049/discussion-on-answer-by-roman-podymov---tableviewcell--tableviewcell).